# How to get file from server

Tags: android

I am doing Multimedia application using client server interaction, for that i uploaded some media files in apache tomcat server(My server is static). Now i want to display the media files whatever uploaded in sever to my android device (device is a client). I am confused how to get files from server to client. please guide me. give me some tutorials link. Note:i am using for multiple client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write a streamer, if you want to play an mp3 file in real time